# How to debug PHP database code?

Tags: php, forms, authentication

I am new in PHP and need help with my below code. When I am entering wrong userid instead of giving the message "userid does not exist" it is showing "password/id mismatch. Please guide me where I am wrong.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $id = $_POST['userid'];
    $pwd = $_POST['paswd'];
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "????", "????", "??????");
    if ($con) {
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid=$id");
        if ($result) {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            if ($row["userid"] == $id && $row["paswd"] == $pwd) {
                echo "Welcome! You are a authenticate user";
                if ($id == $pwd)
                //my default login id and password are same
                {
                    header("Location: changepwd.html");
                } else {
                    header("Location: dataentry.html");
                }
            } else {
                echo "ID/Password Mismatch";
            }
        } else {
            echo "User does not Exist !!!";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Connection failed - ".mysqli_error()." -- ".mysqli_errno();
    }
?>
```

Comment: You're using MySQLi, so start by learning how to use prepared statements with bind variables; and learn not to store passwords in plaintext

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` cannot work with mysqli_*

Comment: mixing mysqli/mysql also printing explicitly before header(), so header() won't work

Comment: Pay attention to your formatting. Formatting has nothing to do with the answer to your question. But you could read your code easely.

Comment: 4 nested if's each of them connected with else clause, it's sometime hardly to understand which block will be executed, if it's not formated well, so +1 for the above comment. Btw. Querying only by user_id seems to me unusual case and structured this way can easily be hacked by executing whatever the user want after the user_id (`1 OR 1=1`, `1 UNION ALL ...`,...)

Comment: I have already changed mysql_fetch_array to mysqli and as far as hacking is concerned I am first trying to write a code which will work and then learn ways to make it secure.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem you have is that you're mixing up between the `mysqli` and `mysql` functions. These two libraries are not compatible with each other; you must only use one or the other.

In other words, the following line is wrong:

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

It needs to be changed to use `mysqli_`.

While I'm here, going off-topic for a moment I would also point out a few other mistakes you're making:

1. You aren't escaping your SQL input. It would be extremely easy to hack your code simply by posting a malicious value to `$_POST['userid']`. You *must* use proper escaping or parameter binding. (since you're using `mysqli`, I recommend the latter; it's a better technique).
2. Your password checking is poor -- you don't appear to be doing any kind of hashing, so I guess your passwords are stored as plain text in the database. If this is the case, then your database is extremely vulnerable. You should always hash your passwords, and never store the actual password value in the database.

I've gone off topic, so I won't go any further into explaining those points; if you need help with either of these points I suggest asking separate questions (or searching here; I'm sure there's plenty of existing advice available too).

Answer (score 0):

```
else 
{
echo "ID/Password Mismatch"; 
}
```

is connected with the
    if($row["userid"]==$id && $row["paswd"]==$pwd)
    {

So since you are giving a wrong id. It echo's: `ID/Password Mismatch`
Also the `else` at `if ($result) {` wont ever show since

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid=$id");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some additionnal checks:

select * return 1 row (not 0, and not more)

you need to protect the datas entered by the html form (for example someone could enter `1 or 1` to return all rows

```
<?php
session_start();

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "????", "????", "??????");
$id  = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['userid']);
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['paswd']);
if ($con) {
    // don't even do the query if data are incomplete
    if (empty($id) || empty($pwd)
      $result = false;
    else
    {
      // optionnal : if userid is supposed to be a number
      // $id = (int)$id;
      $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid='$id'");
    }
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) != 1)
      $result = false;
    if ($result) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if ($row["userid"] == $id && $row["paswd"] == $pwd) {
            echo "Welcome! You are a authenticate user";
            if ($id == $pwd)
            //my default login id and password are same
                {
                header("Location: changepwd.html");
            } else {
                header("Location: dataentry.html");
            }
        } else {
            echo "ID/Password Mismatch";
        }
    } else {
        echo "User does not Exist, or incomplete input";
    }
} else {
    echo "Connection failed - " . mysqli_error() . " -- " . mysqli_errno();
}
?>
```

Comment: -1, bad advice and you are protecting literally nothing. Password is not appended to the query, and ID can still be `1 OR 1=1 LIMIT 1`, mysqli_real_escape_string won't put slashes on it, so the query would look like `SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid=1 OR 1=1 LIMIT 1`

Comment: sorry I forgot the quote when I wrote userid=, but it's always better to use prepared statements anyway

Comment: Yes, because this way you should be aware of the char encoding i.e. `&#x27;` evaluates to single quote

Comment: I have made some changes and getting different error. please check my post

Comment: You can easily solve your new problem by yourself. understand the error message and see what you do in your code, where is `$result` and if the `{` and `}` are correctly placed, and correct it. We can't do all the debug work.

Answer (score 0):

Try with isset() method while you are checking if **$result** empty or not.

that is in line

```
     if ($result) {.......}
```

use

```
     if (isset($result)) { .......}
```

Answer (score -1):

$result is always true, because mysqli_query() only returns false if query failed.
You could check if $result has actual content with empty() for example.

Answer (score -1):

```
You can use this sql compare password as well with userid
```

$sql=  "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid='".$id.", and password='".$pwd."'";

Comment: Does not solve anything and leaves the same or more problems present

Comment: I don't think there is any problem with this answer, in sql when compare password and username both and enter wrong credential thne $result is set by 0 so it will print  echo "User does not Exist !!!"; as requirement.

Comment: Result won't be false, however you still leave all the bad design, sql injection, mixing 2 mysql api's and so on